# C# doesn't save changes

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I have a `.mdf` database file in Visual Studio with a few tables. But when I restart the program all changes are gone.

Here is my connection string:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Diepeschrath.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30
```

Also I have a settings file, but there the changes won't save either.

On both:

- Copy to Output Directory: Copy always

I tried it with debug, release and copy all the files to the desktop

Edit:

I update the code just with UPDATE.

For example:

```
String cmdString1 = "Update Pferde SET ReithalleHeute=ReithalleMorgen, PaddockHeute=PaddockMorgen, LongierZHeute = LongierZMorgen, ReithalleMorgen=0, PaddockMorgen=0, LongierZMorgen=0";

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
String conString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Diepeschrath.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
con.ConnectionString = conString;        
con.Open();  
SqlCommand cmd;

cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdString1, con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

con.close();
```

When the program runs I see the data in the dataview, but when I restart it's like I never add something.

Comment: You need to show your code, especially the code that saves your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was that I don't save the .settings and when it restarts it overwrites my database.

For all who have .settings and want so save it:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Answer (score 3):

> On both: Copy to Output Directory: Copy always

The changes you make are being saved, they are just are being saved in the mdf file in the output directory, because you have "Copy always" set you are overwriting the file that holds the changes every build and it just looks like it is not saving.

Switch Copy always to "Copy if newer" or don't use `AttachDbFilename` and instead manually attach the sql database and keep it in a path outside of your project's build directory.

Comment: I changed it to "copy if newer" but it won't help :-/

Comment: Then use the other option, get rid of  `AttachDbFilename`, attach the database manually, and use a normal [connection string](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) to specify which allready connected database to use.